# How to open page with ons-tabbar, and display specific tab

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

How can I open a page, which contains an ons-tabbar inside, and tell it to show a specific tab, using ons-navigator? I have a menu with some buttons, and depending which one is pushed, it has to be displayed the tabbar page, with a specific tab active.

This is what I have tried so far:

index.html (Main page)

```
<body>
  <ons-navigator animation="slide" var="app.navi">
    <ons-page>
      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Inicio</div>
      </ons-toolbar>
      <div>
        <p style="text-align: center">
          <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="app.navi.pushPage('tabs.html', {params: { tab: 0 }});">OPEN TAB 0</ons-button>
        </p>
        <p style="text-align: center">
          <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="app.navi.pushPage('tabs.html', {params: {tab: 1}});">OPEN TAB 1</ons-button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-navigator>
</body>
```

tabs.html

```
<div ng-controller="TabsCtrl">
  <ons-tabbar var="tabbar" position="top">
    <ons-tabbar-item
        icon="home"
        label="Home"
        page="page0.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
    <ons-tabbar-item
        icon="comment"
        label="Comments"
        page="page1.html"></ons-tabbar-item>
  </ons-tabbar>
</div>
```

AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('myControllers', [])
.controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  // Trying to set active tab on the controller
  $scope.tabbar.setActiveTab($scope.ons.navigator.getCurrentPage().options.params.tab);
}]);
```

However, when I push a buton in the main page, the debugger says that cannot call method `setActiveTab` on undefined. I know that this may be because the tabbar hasn't been created when the controller is executed, but I can't figure out how to show a specific tab when the page is displayed, based on some navigator parameter.

Comment: you need to provide code, what you've tried, and where the issue is. Otherwise you won't get much help. Also, I don't see any mention of AngularJS here, but you did tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's true that when the controller is executed there won't be any tabbar object, but it will be created immediately after.

So you could use `setImmediate(fn)` in the controller to call `setActiveIndex(idx)`.

Example:

```js
angular.module('app', ['onsen'])

.controller('TabsController', function() {
  setImmediate(function() {
    var tabIndex = app.navi.getCurrentPage().options.params.tab;
    app.tabbar.setActiveTab(tabIndex);
  });
});
```

Pen:
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/XJryPM

Actually, in 1.2.0 there is an `'ons-tabbar:init'` DOM event that you could listen to which is probably better to use. The event object will attach the tabbar object so you could do something like:

```js
someElement.addEventListener('ons-tabbar:init', function(event) {
  var tabBar = event.component;
  tabBar.setActiveTab(someIndex);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks. The first solution worked like a charm. With the second one, seems appropiate, but I have some doubts: if I use the init event, what is `someElement`? And in the AngularJS context, where should I set the event listener?

Comment: Great! You could attach the event listener to `document` but maybe in an Angular app the first solution is better.